# No consigo cambiar la página de Inicio de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Es la primera vez que me ocurre, y ya no se donde mirar o que opción me esta pisando el cambio de pagina de inicio, lo he intentando con varias paginas y no lo acepta.
Lo raro es que cuando vuelvo a ir a las opciones para modificarlo sale la pagina tal y como le digo, pero luego acceso a la web y no se ve.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué configuraste para cambiarla? ¿Revisaste si esa página no tiene redirección en el `.htaccess`
?

Comment: Pues tanto lo he modificado desde Personalizador de temas y desde ajustes Lectura, y no veo ninguna redirección desde .htaccess

Comment: ¿Ahí le indicas una página o es post? ¿La página tiene el estado `published` (publicada)? ¿Tienes algún tema de particulares instalado?

Comment: Si, es una página y el tema es divi con woocommerce y esta publicada

Comment: He trabajado como siempre, es decir, mi workflow, vengo de un entorno de desarrollo y he pisado con el all in one migration, pero es algo que hace muchas veces a la semana, por eso me ha extrañado tanto

Comment: Sugeriría que actives temporalmente el modo debug de WP para poder ver si están ocurriendo errores en el código.

Comment: Gracias, me he llevado una copia del server de producción a desarrollo y allí me va de lujo, quizás sea mejor empezar de nuevo el server de producción, creo que el error debe estar en este paso

Comment: Las migraciones automáticas a veces dejan algo detrás. Si fuera tú migraría todo manual, tampoco es tan complicado, así sabes a qué atenerte.

Answer (score 0):

Para cada página o page de WP existe la opción de especificar la plantilla( o molde ) que se utilizará para visualizar esa página. Fíjate en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mira en otras páginas que sí se visualizan corréctamente que plantilla se está usando y luego en la página de inicio cual es la que usa. Cambiala para dejarlas como las otras o a una que realice la visualización tal y como deseas.

¡ Suerte !

Answer (score 0):

En esa misma ventana que muestras, ahí donde dice "Página de inicio" busca entre esas opciones una que diga Homepage y la seleccionas, suele ser la definida por defecto en el tema que has instalado, el Home suele ser la página por defecto de Wordpress.

No se si te mostrará algo parecido a esto:

[image: Captura opciones]